# Best practice: Redirect when deleting in Laravel using Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Im using Laravel 5.5 to build a webapp and I have encountered a problem.
Deleting a record from my database (a project) using AJAX works properly, it gets deleted and Ajax returns the data that was just erased.

Im doing this in the project list view, so the datatable refreshes and doesn't show this record anymore.

Problem is when I delete the record from the project page instead of the list page. It gets deleted and Ajax returns the proper values but the user remains in the same page showing the deleted data; if they refresh the page they get a 404 error (obviously since we just deleted the record).

What is the best practice in this case? 
Should I redirect users to the project list page? In this case how? And what will happen if there are more calls to this delete command elsewhere in the app?

Thank you!

Comment: If it's on the item view then probably redirect to the list view and if on the list view then reload the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just redirect when the ajax response confirms success.

`window.location.href = '/somewhere-else'`

Comment: But I dont want that in the list page since it automatically refreshes the data from the db. It would be just in the item view.

Comment: problem is that the ajax function is the same, since I dont want to duplicate code. how can i check if its the item view or the list page in the code?
List page: /projects
Item page: /projects/15

Comment: add an extra argument and default it to false. on the page you want to redirect from, pass true as the last argument

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define some redirect when page is returning `404`  error